# Typescript: type for Date.getTime()

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there a data type like Timestamp which I can use for Date().getTime()

`const currentTime = new Date().getTime();`

Comment: The type returned by `Date.getTime` is `number`.

Answer (score 1):

`getTime` returns number

```
timeVar: number = new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: @DebanjanB can you please try to provide more logical answer to this question? at least please take a look and just try. The only explaination is this!! I totally disagree with you on this manner!!